# One reusable animation for multiple Angular components?

Tags: angular, animation, components, angular-animations

I am using animations in my Angular app, and many components use the same animation but for that I copy/paste the animation in each component. Can we reuse the animations without applying it on individual components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an `animations.ts` file, and import the animation you want in each component:

**Example `animations.ts`**

```
import {
  trigger,
  style,
  animate,
  transition,
  state,
  group
} from '@angular/animations';


export const rotations = [
  trigger('rotatedState', [
    state('default', style({
      transform: 'rotate(0)'
    })),
    state('rotated', style({
      transform: 'rotate(-180deg)'
    })),
    transition('rotated => default',
      animate('400ms ease-out')
    ),
    transition('default => rotated',
      animate('400ms ease-in')
    )
  ])
];

export const someOtherAnimations = [
  ...
];
```

**Now import in `component.ts`:**

```
import { rotations } from 'app/animations';

@Component({
  ...
  animations: [rotations],
})
```

**Now you can use in your `component.html`:**

```
<img @rotatedState >
```